# Dot product between two vectors with complex components

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I have the following vectors:

$$\vec{a} = (-2i, 4, 5)$$

$$\vec{b} = (6, 5, i)$$

I need to get $<\vec{a}|\vec{b}>$. I did the normal procedure: $<\vec{a}|\vec{b}> = (-2i)(6) + (4)(5) + (5)(i) = 20 -7i$

But the answer is supposed to be $20+17i$, where did I had my mistake? Thanks.

Comment: As J.W.Tanner explains, you have to take the complex conjugate of $a$. This preserves the useful property of the dot product that $<x\;|\;x>=0$ if and only if $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that, when taking the dot product of vectors with complex components, you should take the complex conjugates of the components of one of the vectors.

The correct answer is $\overline{(-2i)}(6)+\overline{(4)}(5)+\overline{(5)}(i)=(2i)(6)+(4)(5)+(5)(i)$.

Comment: I think "one of the vectors" should be "the first vector".

Comment: @TonyK:  I hedged because I think some have the convention to conjugate the components of the second vector, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53148/interpretation-of-dot-product-of-complex-vectors)

Comment: You may be right, but I've never seen that.

Comment: @TonyK:  cf. discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535786/dot-product-over-complex-vectors-conjugate-first-or-second)

Comment: I stand corrected!