# Norm of the sum of complex vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, summation, vectors, normed-spaces

Say that we have $n$ complex-valued vectors $\mathbf{z}_{i}$ and we want to evaluate:

$$\left\|\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbf{z}_{i}\right\|_2^{2}$$

Now, I know that for real vectors $\mathbf{x}_{i}$ it holds:

$$\left\|\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbf{x}_{i}\right\|_2^{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\|\mathbf{x}_{i}\right\|_2^{2}+\sum_{i \neq j} \mathbf{x}_{i} \cdot \mathbf{x}_{j}$$
But when dealing with complex vectors, the last term with the inner product will be a complex number in general so I am not sure that this formula generalizes for this case. What am I missing?

Comment: $x_i.x_j$ gets replaced by $Re (x_i.\overline {x_j})$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53148/interpretation-of-dot-product-of-complex-vectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generalizing @enzotib's answer to $n$ terms, since $\Vert z\Vert_2^2=z^\ast\cdot z$ we have$$\left\Vert\sum_iz_i\right\Vert_2^2=\sum_iz_i^\ast\cdot\sum_jz_j=\sum_{ij}z_i^\ast\cdot z_j=\sum_iz_i^\ast\cdot z_i+\sum_{i\ne j}z_i^\ast\cdot z_j.$$

Comment: Shouldn't the last term be the real part of that dot product?

Comment: @LeonardoMassai it's real anyway because the term is $\sum_{i<j}(z_i^\ast\cdot z_j+z_j^\ast z_i)=2\Re\sum_{i<j}z_i^\ast\cdot z_j$.

Comment: +1, more general

Answer (score 1):

For two complex numbers
$$
\|z_1+z_2\|^2=(z_1+z_2)^*(z_1+z_2)=\|z_1\|^2+\|z_2\|^2+(z_1^*z_2+z_1z_2^*)=\\
\|z_1\|^2+\|z_2\|^2+2Re(z_1^*z_2)
$$
easily extended to $n$.